# Is it possible to use 'print >>' in Python 2 without newline and white spaces?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

In the following code:

```
with open("output", "w") as f:
    print >> f, "foo"
    print >> f, "bar"
```

The 'output' file will be:

```
foo
bar
```

How to avoid newline and white spaces using `print >>`?

**P.S.:** I'm actually wanting to know if it is possible to do it using `print >>`. I know other ways in which I can avoid the '\n', such as `f.write("foo")` and `f.write("bar")`.

Also, I know about the trailing comma. But that prints `foo bar`, instead of `foobar`.

Comment: Why, **why** do you want to do it using a deprecated construct?

Comment: I just wanted to know, out of curiosity, if it is possible. I like to know different syntaxes.

Answer (score 5):

A trailing comma makes the `print` statement do magic, like printing no newline unless there’s no further output ([not documented!](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement)):

```
print >>f, "foo",
```

but that’s not really helpful if you want a consistent no-newline policy (and because you have a second `print`, which will print a space). For that, use Python 3’s print function:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

and

```
print("foo", end="", file=f)
```